linked hashmap get the first inserted
I have this LinkedHashMap which keep the order of the K-V pairs on the insertion order.
Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    if (i == 3000 || i == 4000  || i == 5000) {
        map.put(i, "REGION2");
    }else{
        map.put(i, UserServiceImpl.Country.randomCountry());
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : map.entrySet())
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " "
            + e.getValue());

So I want to get the first inserted K-V pair in a hashmap. For that I need to use LinkedHashMap, see more info on  this thread.
Now I want to get the firstly inserted K-V pair and remove that from the linked list.
So if REGION2 was inserted at i = 3000, i = 4000, and i = 5000 in a loop, I want to get the map value of <3000, REGION2> since that was the earliest to be inserted in. And then remove that <3000, REGION2> from the map.
How can I achieve this in code ?
I know that
String firstKey = banks.keySet().iterator().next();

Will give me the first key inserted with correct iteration. See this thread
Yet I want to get the first K-V pair inserted based on the value, such as REGION2. Helps are appreciated

You'll just have to iterate the entryset.

If you need this quickly you will need to reconsider your data structure.

Yes i'd love to have the execution time to be fast. @user207421

You should be aware of this

If your existing map is SequencedMap<K,V> you need to maintain a second data structure, Map<V,List<K>> or Map<V,List<Pair<V,K>>>.

I think this will work
banks.entryset().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals("REGION2"))
    .findFirst()
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .ifPresent(banks::remove);

On mobile and haven't tried to run this so syntax might have minor issues.
